# "WICKED" entries in the default nginx vhost's logs

Tags: linux, malware, http

I have a small VPS running nginx, and for a long time now (several months, since I rented it) it has been collecting weird entries in its default (listen  80 default;) vhost's logs:

```
109.x.x.121 - - [07/Dec/2012:07:42:43 +0100] "GET /webpanel/gate.php HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "WICKED"
```

there is a lot of those, from a few different IPs

```
# grep WICKED /var/log/nginx/x.access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
18
```

There are also recurring ones, like this one which polls the server every minute

```
95.x.x.4 - - [07/Dec/2012:08:17:35 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
95.x.x.4 - - [07/Dec/2012:08:18:37 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
95.x.x.4 - - [07/Dec/2012:08:19:39 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

until it stops. According to its PTR and whois information, this particular IP belongs to a dynip range of some German cable company so it's probably not a monitoring service.

Now, here's my question, **what am I looking at?**

Was the IP being used in some sort of bot herding before I got it? Or maybe my server was compromised? Those entries were showing up when I only had sshd and nginx serving static sites so pretty much nothing to exploit.

EDIT: yeah, I inflated the numbers unwittingly because I forgot to sort, fixed.

Comment: We must perform an exorcism to cleanse these WICKED NUMBERS!

Answer (score 2):

The last two fields by default are the referrer and user agent fields ([nginx reference](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule)). Normally you'd see something there like a browser (Mozilla), search bot (Googlebot), command line program ("Wget", "curl") etc. there. Whoever is running something against your server is using "WICKED" as a user agent string.

Comment: And I'd also point out that this means nothing specific. Just someone decided to call their program "WICKED"; that's really all you can conclude directly.

Comment: Yup, could be custom-made, could be a regular browser with a custom user agent. No telling.